# Docker run does not mount the local folder

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, docker, ubuntu

I need to use a docker image which has compiled versions of certain programs that are very hard to compile from scratch.

I need to run a program in that environment.

I installed docker and pulled the image (john/custom:py2).

But how do I run a program (A Python program that works in the docker environment) using the environment provided to me by docker, sending in the local folder as input and producing the output back to my local system.

So far all resources tutorials show me how to work inside docker and not the problem I want.

Thanks for our help.

The technical issue is:

```
docker run -it -v /tmp:/home/ubuntu/myfolder/ john/custom:py2
```

This sends me to root. But I see none of the folders or files of myfolder in the shell.

i.e `ls` command gives empty results

How can I run a program inside this docker environment that works on the input of the folder and writes in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've reversed the order on the volume syntax. The first half is the host location or volume source, while the second half is the target directory inside the container where the volume is mounted. Try:

```
docker run -it -v /home/ubuntu/myfolder/:/tmp john/custom:py2
```

To mount `myfolder` into the container's `/tmp` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a little variation using the ubuntu container and it works for me.

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
$ docker run -it -v /tmp:/home/ubuntu/myfolder ubuntu:latest
$ ls /home/ubuntu/myfolder
```

Try this and see whether or not it works for you.
I would also try mounting other directories besides /tmp to a directory in the docker container. For example:

```
$ mkdir /home/john/foo
$ docker run -it -v /home/john/foo:/home/ubuntu/foo ubuntu:latest
```

/tmp is a little special and I don't know if it's a good idea to mount that directory inside docker.